# calculate 95 percentile of the list values in python

Tags: python, percentile

I have a dictionary in my program and each of the value is a list of response times. I need to calculate the 95 percentile response time for each of these lists. I know how to calculate the average, But have no idea about 95 percentile calculation. Any pointers would be appreciated.

The following is the dictionary output of my program

finalvalues = {'https://lp1.soma.sf.com/img/chasupersprite.qng?v=182-4': ['505', '1405', '12', '12', '3'], 'https://lp1.soma.sf.com/img/metaBar_sprite.dsc': ['154', '400', '1124', '82', '94', '108']}

Comment: Check this out : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511478-finding-the-percentile-of-the-values/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
for i in finalvalues.values():
    print np.percentile(map(int,i),95)
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I wanted the 95 percentile of the values inside a dictionary. Thanks Richie!

Answer (score 2):

Use `scipy.stats.norm.interval(confidence, loc=mean, scale=sigma)` where *confidence* is a value between 0 and 1, in your case, it would be .95. *mean* would be the mean of your data and *sigma* would be your sample standard deviation. The output of this will be a tuple, where the first value is the lower bound and the second value is the upper bound on the interval. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is only applicable to a normal distribution.